# How can i use code from codepen in my project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mdbootstrap

I want to use the code from here in my project
https://codepen.io/zso2u/pen/jKmmqB

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 class="text-center mb-3">Bootstrap Multi-Card Carousel</h1>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto">
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f44242/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/418cf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/3ed846/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/42ebf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f49b41/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 5</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f4f141/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 6</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/8e41f4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 7</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my project but when i copy paste the code to my site its not displayed correctly for some reason and i cant figure out why.

Here is my site
abusive-secretary.surge.sh

How can i use this code inside my project?

When i copy and paste it i can only see 1 card at a time but i need to see 3 cards at a time.

What i try to do is make something like you can see on top of this page
https://www.dapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use this Bootstrap 4 CDN from MDBootstrap. I tried this CDN it works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can use this code in single page or you can make it external css or js file.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <style>
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        /* show 3 items */
        .carousel-inner .active,
        .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
        .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
          display: block;
        }

        .carousel-inner
          .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
        .carousel-inner
          .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)
          + .carousel-item,
        .carousel-inner
          .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)
          + .carousel-item
          + .carousel-item {
          transition: none;
        }

        .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
        .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
          position: relative;
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }

        .carousel-inner
          .active.carousel-item
          + .carousel-item
          + .carousel-item
          + .carousel-item {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          right: -33.3333%;
          z-index: -1;
          display: block;
          visibility: visible;
        }

        /* left or forward direction */
        .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
        .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
        .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
        .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left
          + .carousel-item
          + .carousel-item
          + .carousel-item {
          position: relative;
          transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
          visibility: visible;
        }

        /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
        .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          z-index: -1;
          display: block;
          visibility: visible;
        }

        /* right or prev direction */
        .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
        .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
        .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
        .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right
          + .carousel-item
          + .carousel-item
          + .carousel-item {
          position: relative;
          transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
          visibility: visible;
          display: block;
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }

    </style>

    <body>

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="text-center mb-3">Bootstrap Multi-Card Carousel</h1>
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto">
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f44242/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/418cf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/3ed846/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/42ebf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f49b41/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 5</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f4f141/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 6</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/8e41f4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 7</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>


    <script>
      $("#myCarousel").on("slide.bs.carousel", function(e) {
      var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
      var idx = $e.index();
      var itemsPerSlide = 3;
      var totalItems = $(".carousel-item").length;

      if (idx >= totalItems - (itemsPerSlide - 1)) {
        var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
        for (var i = 0; i < it; i++) {
          // append slides to end
          if (e.direction == "left") {
            $(".carousel-item")
              .eq(i)
              .appendTo(".carousel-inner");
          } else {
            $(".carousel-item")
              .eq(0)
              .appendTo($(this).find(".carousel-inner"));
          }
        }
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: it doesnt work- im using the mdbootstrap cdn and when i add the bootstrap4 cdn the whole thing is messed up

Comment: Ok, let me check again because i am using the Online CDN of bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

Example in codepen use old Bootstrap version (4.0.0). You probably use 4.4.1. That's why this example didn't work properly on your site.